# WPF ScrollViewer and TextWrapping inside datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, word-wrap, datagridcell

I want ScrollViewer and TextWrapping inside datagrid cell. So text inside cell will not crop, and when height of text(block) overflows cell, scrollviewer becomes visible. To sum up I just want to fit all my text into datagrid cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Could always just change the style instead, but it's just the TextWrapping field that you need.